# React and Flex layout how to use them

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to use React and flexbox.Normally i can use flexbox at react native but icouldnt achive in react.js

this is my Css file

```
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav {
    background-color: red;
    flex:1
}
.main {
    background-color: blue;
    flex:1
}
```

This is my js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './background.css';
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Navbar from './navbar'

class Back extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nav"></div>
          <div className="main"></div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Back;
```

I got just a white screen what might be a problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Your `nav` and `main` divs have no content in them! https://codesandbox.io/s/9QPvrw3pY

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer. Also, accepting answers is a great way to motivate users to provide useful answers on your future questions, **and** it increase your reps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the `wrapper` is positioned absolute, and have no content to grow with, its width collapse to 0.

So simply remove `position: absolute` from the `.wrapper, html, body` rule.

If you still want to use `position: absolute`, you need to also give the wrapper a width.

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works at normal HTML and  Css but ı couldnt have the same result at react ? any idea ?

Comment: @techsnake If you use the dev. tools built in browsers (right click in the webpage and chose _Inspect_) you can then step through the rendered elements and see the styles they have. If you have a link, or a fiddle, to this sample I can very quick check that and see why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **float:left** in the wrapper class.