# How to return align items one after other in a div using css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

code is like below,

```
const renderInfo = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>Name</div>
            <div>Name1</div>
            <div>Type</div>
            <div>Type1</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

I want it to display like below,

[image]

but is currently shown like this with above code
[image]

Could someone help me fix this alignment. thanks.

Comment: Did you try to fix it? You're expected to at least try then come back with questions about issues if you have them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Flex layout how to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844966/react-and-flex-layout-how-to-use-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap it inside a container after that you can use `flexbox`, `display: block` etc.**

**Using Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Name1</div>
  <div>Type</div>
  <div>Type1</div>
</div>
```

**Using `display: block`**

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Name1</div>
  <div>Type</div>
  <div>Type1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can have styles inside `div` like so:

```
<div style={{ display: "block" }}>
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Name1</div>
  <div>Type</div>
  <div>Type1</div>
</div>
```